# I am not getting values by passing variable using IN query in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am passing string values from my code like `'12th Standard/Ordinary National Diploma,Higher National Diploma'` to SQL query, but I am not getting any values and nothing showing any result.

My SQL query:

```
declare @qua varchar(250),@final varchar(250),@Qualification varchar(250)
set @Qualification= '12th Standard/Ordinary National Diploma,Higher National Diploma'
set @qua =replace(@Qualification,',',''',''')
set @final= ''''+@qua+''''

select  * from mytablename in(@final)
```

Result: Data is not displaying

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would create a temp table for your comma seperated values and then would join with your actual table to get the data.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause)

Comment: why we require temp table, can you update the answer.@SMA

Comment: Please update the answer.@lad2025

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead do it using a table variable like

```
declare @tbl table(qual varchar(250));
insert into @tbl
select '12th Standard/Ordinary National Diploma'
union
select 'Higher National Diploma';
select  * from mytablename where somecolumn in(select qual from @tbl);
```

Answer (score 2):

Despite trying to put quote marks in there, you're still only passing a single string to the `IN`. The string just contains embedded quotes and SQL Server is looking for that single long string.

You also don't seem to be comparing a column for the `IN`.

Your best bet is to pass in multiple string variables, but if that's not possible then you'll have to write a function that parses a single string into a resultset and use that. For example:

```
SELECT
    Column1,    -- Because we never use SELECT *
    Column2
FROM
    MyTableName
WHERE
    qualification IN (SELECT qualification FROM dbo.fn_ParseString(@qualifications))
```

Comment: Can you write function fn_ParseString  for above  code.

Comment: Did you search for such a function? Both Stackoverflow and Google will yield results if you simply look. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco

Answer (score 1):

You can insert all your search criteria in one table and then can easily do a lookup on the main table, example below:

```
 DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (Name VARCHAR(10), Qualification VARCHAR(50))
   DECLARE @Search TABLE (Qualifications VARCHAR(50))

   INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('User1','12th Standard'), ('User2','Some Education'),
                            ('User3','Ordinary National Diploma'), ('User4','Some Degree'),
                            ('User5','Higher National Diploma')

    INSERT INTO @Search VALUES ('12th Standard'),('Ordinary National Diploma'),('Higher National Diploma')

    SELECT MT.*
    FROM @MyTable MT
        INNER JOIN (SELECT Qualifications FROM @Search)  S ON S.Qualifications = MT.Qualification
```

Answer (score 0):

As previous said, you are passing a string with commas, not comma separated values. It needs to be split up into separate values.

You can do this by passing the qualification string into XML which you can use to turn it into separate rows of data.
The `IN` parameter will then accept the data as separate values.

```
DECLARE @Qualifications as varchar(150) = '12th Standard/Ordinary National Diploma,Higher National Diploma'
Declare @Xml XML;
SET @Xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@Qualifications, char(44),'</r><r>') + '</r></root>';
select *
from MyTableName
Where MyTableName.Qualification in 
    (select r.value('.','varchar(max)') as item
    from @Xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can create a table-valued function that splits according to input like in your case its ',' and then INNER JOIN with the returnColumnname and that particular column that you want to filter

```
SELECT COLUMNS, . . . . 
FROM MyTableName mtn
    INNER JOIN dbo.FNASplitToTable(@qualifications, ',') csvTable 
    ON csvTable.returnColumnName = mtn.somecolumn
```

**Table Valued function might be like:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FNASplitToTable (@string varchar(MAX), @splitType CHAR(1))
RETURNS @result TABLE(Value VARCHAR(100))
AS
BEGIN

      DECLARE @x XML 
      SELECT @x = CAST('<A>' + REPLACE(@string, @splitType, '</A><A>') + '</A>' AS XML)

      INSERT INTO @result            
      SELECT LTRIM(t.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) AS inVal
      FROM @x.nodes('/A') AS x(t)
    RETURN
END   
GO
```